# Cannot insert charts into PowerPoint 2013

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-powerpoint, charts

I cannot insert charts into PowerPoint 2013. Each time I wish to, once I have selected the desired chart type and click 'OK', it simply blinks (exits and reopens). It then returns me to the same window, with nothing happening. Copying and pasting graphs from Excel 2013 works fine. Using Windows 8.1, any solutions short of re installing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method to see if the issue is fixed or not.

Run PowerPoint as Administrator

Go to >file>option>Advance > Display  section -tick  Both options (disable hardware graphic acceleration)  (disable slide show hardware graphic acceleration),
Reboot Your PC
Now open Excel apps tab and then open PowerPoint .
Go to insert tab of PowerPoint and click on chart
Try two times then see if it inset charts or not.

It fixed my problem

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Control Panel | Programs and Features
Click to select Microsoft Office
Click Change in the bar above
When the "Change your installation of ..." dialog appears, choose Repair, then click Continue

Comment: this is not a fix